# Notification action with Service inside PendingIntent doesn't work when app is not running

Tags: android, android-service, android-notifications, retrofit2, android-pendingintent

I have an app that allows responding to notifications through Notification.Actions. So basically, I have a Pending Intent with this

```
Intent actionIntent = actionIntent = new Intent(this, NotificationActionIntentService.class);

actionPendIntent = PendingIntent.getService(
        this,
        requestCodeBtn,
        actionIntent,
        PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT
 );
```

What I do inside my NotificationActionIntentService is a HttpRequest to my BE indicating the update needed to make.

**NOTE**: When app is in the foreground, everything works fine.

Here is the thing:

Upon receiving the GCM, when I press the Notification.Action immediately, everything still works fine.

But, when I wait for like 30 seconds after receiving the GCM before pressing the Notification.Action, the network request isn't completed. The logs only show that it made a network request. But I never get any response. When I view the logs in my BE server. I do not receive the network request.

But when I launch the app manually, the network is then resumed. It seems like the network request is being paused then resumed when the app is already in foreground. (I do not want this behavior because I want it to execute just in the background)

**UPDATE**: After pressing the Notification.Action, after a minute or two (without opening the app) I received `java.net.ConnectException: Failed to connect` in my logs. (Note: I have an internet connection). It seems like the app cannot connect to the network while it is running in background only.

**PS**: Im using **Retrofit 2** in creating my network request. Also I'm using Android N as a test device.

Comment: are you testing on Android O ?

Comment: no, I'm using Android N @Benjamin

Comment: Could you log the livecycle of the background service, to make sure it is not torn down for some magical battery saving reasons, before your request completes?

Comment: @Lukasz Yes, service was not yet destroyed upon making the request. I just found a new hint. After clicking the NotificationAction, after a minute or two (without opening the app). The logs returned a ```java.net.ConnectException: Failed to connect``` error. Note: I have an internet connection. It seems like the app cannot connect to the network while it is not running.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answering my own question:

***source*** -> https://stackoverflow.com/a/41281059/5285687

It turns out that when the device is in power saving mode, the system prevents the background apps from accessing the network.

Here's a solution that you can use.
-> https://stackoverflow.com/a/39167736/5285687

but you need to provide an android Notification for this.